# сортировка матрицы(массив массивов из txt файла)

Tags: python, list

массив состоял до записи в txt -1флот 9 интов.при вызове из txt получить могу только строчку с одним массивом а к элементам в отдельности доступа нет.мб есть какой то другой более выгодный способ например не txt.

```
    `def time_lapse(self): 
        self.values = self.time_scale.get()
        self.temp_varibal.append([round(self.values,2)])  
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.left_eye.get())
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.right_e.get())
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.right_sholder.get())
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.right_hand.get())
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.left_hand.get())
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.left_leg.get())
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.right_leg.get())
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.reserved_1.get())
        self.temp_varibal[-1].append(self.reserved_2.get())

    def write_position(self):
        position = open('results.txt', 'a')
        position.write('\n')
        position.write(str(self.temp_varibal[-1]))
        position.close()`
```

Comment: Вариантов много: CSV, JSON, Excel, HDF5, Parquet, Feather, Avro и т.д.

Comment: Задача стоит в получении элементов/срезов данных, не загружая все данные в память?

Comment: задача первоначально было в сохранении позиции и времени(тобишь первый флот время а остальные позиции загружая данные да)

Comment: сохранил цсв.другая проблема вылезла при вызове первого числа массива добавляется [

Comment: ['4.5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0]']
['[0.043062200956937795', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0]']
['[0.05382775119617225', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0]']
['[0.0645933014354067', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0]']
['[0.0645933014354067', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0]']
['[0.07535885167464115', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0]']
['[0.1076555023923445', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' 0]']

Comment: все так то в порядке не устраивает что не могу обратиться именно к флоту

Comment: Вы можете исправить список - так чтобы его можно было скопировать и использовать в Python (например: `lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`) и вставить непосредственно в вопрос - нажав кнопку "править" (под вопросом)? Или это у вас JSON файл?

Comment: это txt.это копипаст непосредственно из него.сейчас я застрял тупо на том что не могу выполнить сортировку по первому значению массива потому что это стринга

Comment: а что у вас в `temp_varibal`?

Comment: там как раз токи первый флот и 9 интов

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[0.1, 1, 2, 3],[0.2, 11, 22, 33],[0.3, 101, 202, 303]]
cols = ['time', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols)
```

печать:

```
In [62]: df
Out[62]:
   time  col1  col2  col3
0   0.1     1     2     3
1   0.2    11    22    33
2   0.3   101   202   303
```

сохранение в файл:

```
df.to_csv(r'c:/temp/file.csv', index=False)
```

чтение из CSV файла:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'c:/temp/file.csv')
```

результат:

```
In [65]: df2
Out[65]:
   time  col1  col2  col3
0   0.1     1     2     3
1   0.2    11    22    33
2   0.3   101   202   303
```

сортировка:

```
In [66]: df2.sort_values('time', ascending=False)
Out[66]:
   time  col1  col2  col3
2   0.3   101   202   303
1   0.2    11    22    33
0   0.1     1     2     3
```

**UPDATE:**

> смогу ли я производить манипуляции с пандас и отдавать в массив или
>   словарь

В Pandas это делается очень просто:

```
In [3]: df.values.tolist()
Out[3]: [[0.3, 101.0, 202.0, 303.0], [0.2, 11.0, 22.0, 33.0], [0.1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]

In [4]: df.to_dict('records')
Out[4]:
[{'col1': 101.0, 'col2': 202.0, 'col3': 303.0, 'time': 0.3},
 {'col1': 11.0, 'col2': 22.0, 'col3': 33.0, 'time': 0.2},
 {'col1': 1.0, 'col2': 2.0, 'col3': 3.0, 'time': 0.1}]
```

Comment: буду пробывать ,зарание спасибо- величиной с телячью ногу

Comment: И ещё вопрос смогу ли я производить манипуляции с пандас  и отдавать в массив или словарь